# LWUIT ComboBox: Class as the Items

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, dictionary, lwuit

I am using the `ComboBox` in LWUIT. 
My code goes like this.

```
public Locations(String name, int X, int Y)
{
    Name = name;
    xLocation = X;
    yLocation = Y;
}
```

I have made a list of `Locations`

```
private List getLocations()
{
    List list = new List();
    list.addItem(new Locations("Landmark1", 23, 40));
    list.addItem(new Locations("Landmark3", 24, 40));
    list.addItem(new Locations("Landmark4", 25, 40));
    list.addItem(new Locations("Landmark6", 26, 40));

    return list;
}
```

Then made the ComboBox contain the List.

```
comboBox_Locations = new ComboBox(getLocations().getModel());
```

Now, my problem is that how can I display only the Name of the Location on the ComboBox?
I know I can make a list of strings of the Name of the Location like this:

```
private List getLocations()
{
    List list = new List();
    list.addItem(new Locations("Landmark1", 23, 40).Name);
    list.addItem(new Locations("Landmark3", 24, 40).Name);
    list.addItem(new Locations("Landmark4", 25, 40).Name);
    list.addItem(new Locations("Landmark6", 26, 40).Name);

    return list;
}
```

But when I get the `selectedItem`, it only gets the Name and I cannot get the coordinates. 
What I wanted to do is to get the class like this:

```
Object item =  comboBox_Locations.getSelectedItem();
            if (item.getClass() == Locations.class) 
            {
                String Name = ((Locations)item).Name.toString();
                int xCoords = ((Locations)item).getX();
                int yCoords = ((Locations)item).getY();
            }
```

So that I can use the xCoords and yCoords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a renderer:

```
list.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    public Component getCellRendererComponent(Component list, Object model, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) {
        String t = ((Locations)value).getName();
        return super.getCellRendererComponent(list, model, t, index, isSelected);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Although I am not so sure how to use it. I have tried using list.setRenderer before making the list as parameter in comboBox = new ComboBox(list.getModel()); but it does not work. Can you tell me how to use that one? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can try this way. Get the names from the `Locations` and add them to a `ListModel`. Later you must create a `ComboBox` using this `ListModel` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But if I do that, then I will only be getting strings from the selected item in the combobox and not the Location object. What I wanted to do is like the DisplayMemberPath in WPF ComboBox wherein the ComboBox will only display the Name property of the object and not the whole object.

Comment: But If you can get the index from the ComboBox, then you can go to your Locations and know what have you selected in the ComboBox, do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own ListRenderer class.

### ListRenderer.java

```
import com.sun.lwuit.Component;
import com.sun.lwuit.Label;
import com.sun.lwuit.List;
import com.sun.lwuit.list.ListCellRenderer;
public class ListRenderer extends Label implements ListCellRenderer {

    public ListRenderer() {

    }
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List value, Object obj,
            int arg2, boolean isSelected) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Locations listClassObj = (Locations) obj;

        Label listValue = new Label(listClassObj.Name);
        return listValue;
    }
    public Component getListFocusComponent(List arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setText("");
        setFocus(false);
        return this;
    }
    public void repaint() {
    }
}
```

### Midlet:

then, another method to convert string arrays to List array

```
public ComboBox getList(String[] locations,int[] x,int[] y){
Locations[] locationObjs=new Locations[locations.length];
for(int i=0;i<locations.length;i++){
locationObjs=new Locations(locations[i],x[i],y[i]);
}
return new ComboBox(locationObjs);
}

private ComboBox getLocations(){
String[] locations={"landmark1","landmark2","landmark3","landmark4"};
int[] x={23,24,25,26};
int[] y={40,40,40};
ComboBox list=getList(locations,x,y);
return list;
}
```

then,set it for combobox

```
combobox_locations=getLocations();
combobox_locations.setListCellRenderer(new ListRenderer());
```

then use, the below code

```
Object item =  comboBox_Locations.getSelectedItem();
            if (item.getClass() == Locations.class) 
            {
                String Name = ((Locations)item).Name.toString();
                int xCoords = ((Locations)item).getX();
                int yCoords = ((Locations)item).getY();
            }
```